# Legend handles as strings in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I want to have the legend handles as strings.

e.g. I create a plot using:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)

values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
plt.plot(values, marker = '+')
plt.ylim(0,5)

for i,v in enumerate(values):
    ax.annotate(str(v), xy=(i,v), xytext=(-10, 10), textcoords='offset points', fontsize = 12, color = 'r')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Now, I want a legend having handles and labels as

```
handles = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

but

```
plt.legend(handles = handles, labels= labels)
```

doesn't work. Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!